# GoogleVis HTML Tooltips

Tags: r, googlevis

I try to set a picture as tooltip.

Everything works fine with ScatterChart (I use example code from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_Roles_via_googleVis.html). But when I try to use ColumnChart (or any other types) it doesn't work, I see only standard tooltip. What's the problem?

This code works:

```
df <- data.frame(year=1:11,pop=1:11, pop.html.tooltip=letters[1:11])
df$pop.html.tooltip[1]<-'<a href="http://www.geckoanalytics.ru"><img src="http://www.geckoanalytics.ru/images/giraf.jpg" /></a>'
plot(gvisScatterChart(df,options=list(tooltip="{isHtml:'True'}")))
```

This code doesn't work:

```
 df <- data.frame(year=1:11,pop=1:11, pop.html.tooltip=letters[1:11])
 df$pop.html.tooltip[1]<-'<a href="http://www.geckoanalytics.ru"><img src="http://www.geckoanalytics.ru/images/giraf.jpg" /></a>'
 plot(gvisColumnChart(df,options=list(tooltip="{isHtml:'True'}")))
```

Answer (score 2):

`gvisColumnChart` in googleVis version: 0.4.7 has the following interface:

```
gvisColumnChart(data, xvar = "", yvar = "", options = list(), chartid)
```

To make tooltips work you need to pass a vector of column names to be plotted in the `yvar` argument:

```
plot(gvisColumnChart(df,
                     xvar='year',
                     yvar=c('pop','pop.html.tooltip'),
                     options=list(tooltip="{isHtml:'True'}")))
```